# Theorem 3.20 rudin's functional analysis, compactness of $K = f(S \times A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, convex-hulls

Reading through theorem 3.20, Rudin's functional analysis (point (a)).

> If $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ are compact convex sets in a topological vector space $X$ then $co(A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n)$ is compact.

Reporting the proof with my questions

> Let $S$ be the simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of all $s = (s_1,\ldots, s_n)$ with $s_i \geq 0, s_1 + \ldots + s_n = 1$. Put $A = A_1 \times \ldots \times A_n$. Define $f : S \times A \to X$ by
>   $$f(s,a) = s_1 a_1 + \ldots + s_n a_n$$
>   and put $K = f(S \times A)$
>   It is clear that $K$ is compact and that $K \subset co (A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n)$. We will see that this inclusion is actually an equality.

Why is $K$ compact? First of all since $S$ is compact and each $A_i$ is compact then $S \times A$ is also compact, moreover by it's very definition $f$ is continuous a continuous mapping. I'm not sure if compactness of $S \times A$ and continuity of $f$ suffices to show the compactness of $K$. Another thing I was thinking was to cover $f(S \times A)$ with sets of the form

$$
U_{(s,a)} = f(s,a) + V
$$

where $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $K$, and my guess is that with appropriate restrictions of $U_{(s,a)}$ I can work out an appropriate finite subcovers, but It seems a bit complicated, and I'm sure the answer is actually very straighforward

Comment: Central fact: Image $f(K)$ of compact set  $K$ under a continuous mapping  $f$ is compact. Indeed if $(U_i)$ is an open cover of $f(K)$, then by continuity $f^{-1}(U_i)$ is an open cover of $K$. Thus has a finite subcover $(f^{-1}(U_{i_1}),\dots, f^{-1}(U_{i_n}))$, and as a result $(U_{i_1},\dots,U_{i_n})$ is  a finite subcover of $f(K)$.

Comment: So I was close, the trick is opencover $f(S \times A) = K$, pick the counter image $f^{-1}(K)$ which is a compact set. I can find a finite subcover of $f^{-1}(K)$, the image of such subcover is a finite subcover of $K$. Is it right?

Comment: Also just to clarify, the "subcover" doesn't need to be "open" as well right?

Comment: subcover is a subset of original cover, which consists of opens sets, both on range ($f(K)$ in my notation) as well as in domain (b/c inverse image of open sets under a continuous mapping is open).

Answer (score 1):

Your real question is this:

Let $f : C \to X$ be a continuous map from a compact topological space $C$ to a topological space $X$. Is $f(C)$ compact?

It is a well-known fact that the answer is yes. See any textbook on topology or make an internet search (e.g. https://planetmath.org/continuousimageofacompactsetiscompact).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but you couldn't pick a worse website (formatting-wise... the math symbols are unreadable).

Comment: Probably it depends on the browser. Mozilla Firefox works perfectly. Also the comment by Fnacool gives you the short proof. See also https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m54x12/public_html/m54lecture15.pdf Theorem 13.